# PHP Curl (PHP is replacing my periods with underscores)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I've googled around and saw that PHP replaces some variable names with underscores? I didn't think it would happen to my cookies in CURL though. A site I am accessing using CURL in PHP has cookies that have periods in them, whenever they go through CURL the periods are converted to underscores and the cookie no longer works. Does anybody know a solution to this? I can't change the cookie names as I do not own the site